# Visual Studio 2012/2013 in-class member initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, visual-studio-2013

This

```
class X
{
 int x = 2;
 string y {"smt"};
 int tab[3] = {1,2,3}; // or tab[3] {1,2,3}
};
```

is possible in a new C++ 11 standard, as far as i know. However none of this is allowed in Visual Studio 2012 V3 or 2013. The first one gives:

```
error C2864: 'A::a' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
```

the second and third errors about the ';' and '{' .

Does it basically mean that those features are still unavailable in the MS compiler? What compiler actually supports that? I searched for the answers about in-class initialization in Visual but found nothing specific about the latest versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's not available in VS yet. gcc and clang support it.

Comment: [Intel C++ compiler v14](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) also supports

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/resource/news/2013/07/vs2013_CPP_compliance/en/resources/VC_Roadmap.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, non-static data member initializers not supported by [Microsoft compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). Herb Sutter announced that it will be implemented in Visual Studio 2013 RTM. ([Link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-306))

Mr. Sutter said that main reason for such a delay in implementing C++11 features is that Microsoft trying to implement C++14 features same time, because they are tightly coupled.
So, probably, we will gain some C++14 features in VS2013 release too.

Other major compilers:

- [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) supports it (it is first complete C++11 compliant compiler since version 4.8.1 )
- [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) supports since version 3.0
- [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) supports since version 14

Comment: Thank You, this also answers to few of my other questions. :)